# Strange Error when writing basic stuff in VS Community - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I typed this code in VS Community:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    int T[N];

    return 0;
}
```

and it gives me these errors :

```
C2131   expression did not evaluate to a constant
Error (active)      expression must have a constant value
```

in line 7 (int T[N];). I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are not part of Standard C++ and are only supported by various compilers as an extension to the language. Apparently your compiler does not support them. I suggest using `std::vector` instead of relying on something that should not be considered compatible across compilers.

Comment: Start by reading about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) then search for tutorials and/or examples and play around with it until you understand it. If you run into a problem using it, can't figure out how to perform a specific task with it, etc. make another post with all the details and we'll help.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visual c++ compiler does not support variable length arrays. So, the best option in this case would probably be to use a `std::vector`. However, if for some reasons, you are not allowed to use dynamic memory allocation, you can use `_malloca()` to allocate a memory block on the stack.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {
    int* T;
    size_t N = 0;
    const size_t Nmax = _ALLOCA_S_THRESHOLD / sizeof(*T);

    /**
     * read array size from the standard input,
     * return if reading fails or if the requested 
     * array size would exceed the stack size
     */
    std::cin >> N;
    if (std::cin.fail() || N > Nmax) {
        std::cout << "bad input" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    T = (int*)_malloca(N * sizeof(*T));

    /** 
     * do somethig with the array
     * eg: initialize it with zeros
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        T[i] = 0;

    /* free the memory block */
    _freea(T);

    return 0;
}
```

**Related:**

- [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)

**NOTE:**

- Use `_malloca()` with care, see [the msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s.aspx) for details.
- In debug mode, `_malloca` always allocates memory from the heap.

Comment: There's a few other issues with this code.  1: reading from cin might fail.  You could deal with that by either giving N a positive and non-zero value when it is created, or by surrounding the cin >> N bit with an if, etc. .  Also, it's handy to check whether N is less than zero before doing any memory allocation or whatever.  And you'd probably be better off with using a container (such as std::vector<int> eg), rather than using malloc and such.  Resizing a vector and that kind of thing is easier than the malloc way...

Comment: @Tive See the update, the `std::vector` thing has been already mentioned.

Comment: Where is a [call to `_freea`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/734878/673826)? You might introduce a memory leak if allocation happened on heap instead of stack. Especially in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

An array bound is required to be constant, which it isn't in the current code.